# Mimic align environment within tabularx, even more than once per proof

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I have already asked this question: [Define an environment similar to align such that it can be used in tabularx or tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/693382/define-an-environment-similar-to-align-such-that-it-can-be-used-in-tabularx-or-t).

Zarko's answer to that question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/693393/277990) includes an **Addendum** whose code gives exactly the output I want for situations in which there is only one group of successive statements whose '=' symbols are horizontally aligned.

I would like to allow for situations in which there is more than one such group. Please see my remarks in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

% The code given in the Addendum to Zarko's answer:

\begin{tabularx}{250pt}{r l @{\;} >{$\raggedright}X<{$} l}
1. & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Math}
                & Words \\
2. & m & = 9/3  & Words \\
3. &   & = 3    & Words \\
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{1cm}

The above code is succcessful.
However, it cannot cope with situations in which
there are two or more different groups of successive statements
requiring separate horizontal alignments of = symbols.
For example, look what happens to the output if we keep going
(e.g. if we add lines 4 and 5 to the above):

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabularx}{250pt}{r l @{\;} >{$\raggedright}X<{$} l}
1. & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Math}
                & Words \\
2. & m & = 9/3  & Words \\
3. &   & = 3    & Words \\
4. & 34x+2 & = 30/2 & Words \\
5. & & = 15 & Words \\
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{1cm}

We see that the horizontal alignment of all four `=' symbols
is determined by the `=' symbol in line 4,
whereas what we want is for the `=' symbol in line 3
to be aligned with the `=' symbol in line 2
and for the `=' symbol in line 5
to be aligned with the `=' symbol in line 4.
In other words, we want to eliminate
the space between `m' and `= 9/3',
and then align the `=' symbol in line 3
directly below the `=' symbol in line 2.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second column should be right aligned (towards the =) and math so one of these:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}


The above code is succcessful.
However, it cannot cope with situations in which
there are two or more different groups of successive statements
requiring separate horizontal alignments of = symbols.
For example, look what happens to the output if we keep going
(e.g. if we add lines 4 and 5 to the above):

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabularx}{250pt}{r >$r<$ @{} >{\raggedright${}}X<{$} l}
1. & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Math}
                & Words \\
2. & m & = 9/3  & Words \\
3. &   & = 3    & Words \\
4. & 34x+2 & = 30/2 & Words \\
5. & & = 15 & Words \\
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabularx}{250pt}{r >$r<$ @{} >{\raggedright${}}X<{$} l}
1. & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Math}
                & Words \\
2. & m & = 9/3  & Words \\
3. &   & = 3    & Words \\
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{250pt}{r >$r<$ @{} >{\raggedright${}}X<{$} l}
4. & 34x+2 & = 30/2 & Words \\
5. & & = 15 & Words \\
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{1cm}

We see that the horizontal alignment of all four `=' symbols
is determined by the `=' symbol in line 4,
whereas what we want is for the `=' symbol in line 3
to be aligned with the `=' symbol in line 2
and for the `=' symbol in line 5
to be aligned with the `=' symbol in line 4.
In other words, we want to eliminate
the space between `m' and `= 9/3',
and then align the `=' symbol in line 3
directly below the `=' symbol in line 2.

\end{document}
```