# Make contents of several tabularx environments' corresponding columns flush

Tags: tabularx, alignment, width, dimensions

I am in a situation in which it seems desirable to use multiple `tabularx` environments to feign a single one. But I would like for the contents of their right-most columns to be flush left with each other. That is, is there a way to adjust the code below so that, of the words 'Yessir,' 'Yessirino,' and 'Ya-huh,' the one with the greatest width (namely 'Yessirino') is automatically chosen to establish a common width for the right-most column in each of the three `tabularx` environments?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\centering

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r >$r<$ @{} >{\raggedright${}}X<{$} l}

Yes & Yes & Yes & Yessir

\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r >$r<$ @{} >{\raggedright${}}X<{$} l}

Yes & Yes & Yes & Yessirino

\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r >$r<$ @{} >{\raggedright${}}X<{$} l}

Yes & Yes & Yes & Ya-huh

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

(Note: If you would like a partial explanation as to why I would like to use multiple `tabularx` environments to feign a single one, see David Carlisle's answer to a previous question of mine at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/693585/277990. This, however, is probably not essential to my question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you after the following:

[image]

Vertical line before last column is added that it is better visible equal width of last columns in all tables. In the real document you can remove it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newlength\colwidth
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

    \begingroup
\centering
\settowidth\colwidth{Yessirino} % <--- select the longest text in the last columns
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r >{$}r<{$} @{} >{\raggedright${}}X<{$} | p{\colwidth}}
Yes & Yes & Yes & Yessir
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r >{$}r<{$} @{} >{\raggedright${}}X<{$} | p{\colwidth}}
Yes & Yes & Yes & Yessirino
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r >{$}r<{$} @{} >{\raggedright${}}X<{$} | p{\colwidth}}
Yes & Yes & Yes & Ya-huh
\end{tabularx}
    \endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for \begingroup and \endgroup? If I get rid of them the output does not change.

Comment: @NoahJ, by group I limit setting the  `\colwidth` to those tables only (and by this enable to make a different settings for another tables, if needed). If in your document this is not a case, you remove it.