# Error with a command whose purpose is to allow a value to adapt over the course of a document

Tags: ifthenelse, calc

I am trying to write a command that will do the following, in order:

1. Measure the width of an input word.
2. Compare this value to an existing value.
3. If the input word's width is greater, then take on that measure as value. Otherwise, do nothing.

What is going wrong with the following code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength\shape
\setlength{\shape}{1mm}

\newcommand{\shifter}[1]{\ifthenelse
{\shape<\widthof{#1}}              % If the width of the input word is greater than the length of \shape,
{\setlength{\shape}{\widthof{#1}}} % then make the length of \shape equal to the width of the input word.
{}                                 % Otherwise, do nothing.
}%

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\hspace{\shape}Hello % Output as expected: `Hello' is indented 1mm from the left margin.

\shifter{Tyrannosaurus}

\hspace{\shape}Hello % Output not as expected. I wanted `Hello' to be indented the width of the word `Tyrannosaurus' from the left margin. Instead, `Hello' is indented 1mm from the left margin.

\end{document}
```

Possibly relevant: I am getting the following error:

> A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.

Why?

Comment: Your question sounds a bit like an x-y-problem. Can you add a bit more background what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: `\widthof{#1}` is not a length that can be used in ifthenelse, it is a special construct just valid in calc package expressions (which includes `\setlength`)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Ultimately, I am trying to somewhat alter Zarko's answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/693984/277990) to a previous question I had so that it works without obliging the writer to manually plug in the widest word of a group of words (and find out which one is the widest to begin with). See `\settowidth\colwidth{Yessirino} % <--- select the longest text in the last columns` in Zarko's code in the above link. (The purpose of `\colwidth` is to locally establish a column width.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You neither need `ifthen` nor `calc`. Just define a second dimen for comparison, set it to the width with `settowidth` (really descriptive) and use a more robust condition of `etoolbox`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newdimen\shape
\setlength{\shape}{1mm}
\newdimen\shapecompare
\newcommand{\shifter}[1]{%
\settowidth\shapecompare{#1}%
\ifdimless{\shape}{\shapecompare}%
{\setlength{\shape}{\shapecompare}}%
{}%
}%

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\hspace{\shape}Hello

\shifter{Tyrannosaurus}

Tyrannosaurus

\hspace{\shape}Hello 

\end{document}
```

Comment: `! Misplaced alignment tab character &.`

Comment: Oh, just a typo, should have been a `%`. Wrote ot on my smartphone. Thanks for the hint ;)

Comment: From where do you deduce that `\ifthenelse` is deprecated?

Comment: @egreg thought `ifthen` is not recommended, but I may be wrong. Edited in the post.

Comment: My suggestion was related to opinions like mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13866/why-is-the-ifthen-package-obsolete), but even if the package may have some drawbacks it is, of course, not deprecated or obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.

First problem: if you want to compare lengths with `\ifthenelse` you need `\lengthtest` (only comparison between integers needs nothing).

Second problem: `\widthof` doesn't work in `\lengthtest`.

Fix: use a scratch dimension register.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength\shape
\setlength{\shape}{1mm}

\newcommand{\shifter}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{#1}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\shape<\dimen0}}{\setlength{\shape}{\dimen0}}{}%
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\hspace{\shape}Hello

\shifter{Tyrannosaurus}

\hspace{\shape}Hello

Tyrannosaurus % check the space

\end{document}
```

[image]

You don't need `ifthen`, actually:

```
\newcommand{\shifter}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{#1}%
  \ifdim\shape<\dimen0
    \setlength{\shape}{\dimen0}%
  \fi
}
```