# Locally adjust a dimension written into aux

Tags: auxiliary-files, dimensions, grouping

I am writing some code that makes use of a dimension (termed `\shape` below) that gets adjusted several times over the course of the code. *The value `\shape` has by the time the code is finished* is what is used when `\shape` is called. (See my previous question [Make code retrieve a dimensional value from later on in the code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/694294/277990) )

Is there a way to adjust the following code somewhat so that different parts of it are cordoned off from the rest, as it were, and within these parts, `\shape` gets adjusted locally, as opposed to globally, and the value `\shape` has when called within such a part is the value it has by the end of that part of the code (as opposed to *by the end of the (entire) code*)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% The following ~dozen lines are taken from egreg's answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/694439/277990) to a previous question of mine:

\newdimen\shape
\global\shape=0pt
\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{\write\@auxout{\global\shape=\the\shape}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\shifter}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{#1}%
  \ifdim\shape<\dimen0
    \global\shape=\dimen0
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\proofpiece}[1]{%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r >$r<$ @{} >{\raggedright${}}X<{$} p{\shape}}
#1
\end{tabularx}
}%

\newcommand{\rcc}[1]{% ''rightmost column contents''
#1 \shifter{#1}
}

\begin{document}

The following has the output I desire, and the source code is satisfactory:

\proofpiece{
1. & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Math}
                & \rcc{Words}\\
2. & m & = 9/3  & \rcc{Words}\\
3. &   & = 3    & \rcc{Words}\\
}
\proofpiece{
4. & 34x+2 & = 30/2 & \rcc{Wider words}\\
5. &       & = 15   & \rcc{Words}\\
}

\vspace{2cm}

However, suppose we write a second proof in the same document:

\proofpiece{
1. & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Math}
                & \rcc{Words}\\
2. & m & = 2+2  & \rcc{Words}\\
3. &   & = 4    & \rcc{Words}\\
}
\proofpiece{
4. & 34x+2 & = 16/2 & \rcc{Words}\\
5. &       & = 8    & \rcc{Words}\\
}

Unfortunately, the width of the rightmost column is equal to the width of the widest entry in the {\em previous} proof (namely, ``Wider words'').

\end{document}
```

Note: I doubt that this is relevant, but David Carlisle's answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/693585/277990) to one of my previous questions provides context as to why `\proofpiece` is the way it is.

Comment: Does invoking `\shape=0pt` after each `\proofpiece` give you the answer you desire?  If so, you could incorporate that redefinition into the macro.

Comment: If not, then perhaps invoking `\shape=0pt` at the end of each "proof" is what you seek.

Comment: `\AtEndDocument{\write\@auxout{\global\shape=\the\shape}}` is unsafe, you want `\immediate\write` or it might not get written

Comment: just make the dimen `\shape`  a parameter to the environment and pass different dimen to each group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a different dimen register for each group, also beware underfull box warnings from missing `%`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% The following ~dozen lines are taken from egreg's answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/694439/277990) to a previous question of mine:

\makeatletter
\newdimen\shapea
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\global\shapea=\the\shapea}}
\newdimen\shapeb
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\global\shapeb=\the\shapeb}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\shifter}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{#1}%
  \ifdim\shape<\dimen0
    \global\shape=\dimen0
  \fi
}


\newcommand{\proofpiece}[2]{%
\let\shape#1%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r >$r<$ @{} >{\raggedright${}}X<{$} p{#1}}
#2
\end{tabularx}%
}%

\newcommand{\rcc}[1]{% ''rightmost column contents''
#1 \shifter{#1}
}

\begin{document}

The following has the output I desire, and the source code is satisfactory:

\proofpiece\shapea{
1. & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Math}
                & \rcc{Words}\\
2. & m & = 9/3  & \rcc{Words}\\
3. &   & = 3    & \rcc{Words}\\
}
\proofpiece\shapea{
4. & 34x+2 & = 30/2 & \rcc{Wider words}\\
5. &       & = 15   & \rcc{Words}\\
}

\vspace{2cm}

However, suppose we write a second proof in the same document:

\proofpiece\shapeb{
1. & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Math}
                & \rcc{Words}\\
2. & m & = 2+2  & \rcc{Words}\\
3. &   & = 4    & \rcc{Words}\\
}
\proofpiece\shapeb{
4. & 34x+2 & = 16/2 & \rcc{Words}\\
5. &       & = 8    & \rcc{Words}\\
}

Unfortunately, the width of the rightmost column is equal to the width of the widest entry in the {\em previous} proof (namely, ``Wider words'').

\end{document}
```